# My Bootstrap Dropdown is not Working HTML/CSS/BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my dropdown in my navigation bar is not working; nothing happens when it is clicked. I also find it strange because I copied this code from somewhere else, and it isn't working. I have checked for typos multiple times but came up with nothing.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website Template</title>
        <!-- links to the css page and bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- BEGIN NAVBAR -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li><a class="" href="#">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Text</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <p>Paragraph.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not referencing the jQuery library and Bootstrap.js library in your `<head>` tag..
The navbar requires a javascript library (collapse.js), all you need is [here](http://ttp://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), check the text in the big red box.

EDIT: Put this CDN tag in your `<head>`, make sure to put the latest jQuery library before this line.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```